# Refactoring big ball of mud; not sure static is being used properly here. Advice?

Tags: c#, static, refactoring

I'll admit sometimes the deeper nuances of the keyword static escape me.

Here's what I'm seeing:

```
public partial class Default : CSSDEIStatusBase
{
    private static Default _csWitWeb;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DoStuff
        _csWitWeb = this;
        //OtherStuff
    }

    public static void ForceLoadSyncOperation(int? index)
    {
        Default._csWitWeb.LoadSelectedSyncOperation(index);
    }
}
```

The only references to ForceLoadSyncOperation are:

```
Default.ForceLoadSyncOperation(index);
```

or

```
Default.ForceLoadSyncOperation(null);
```

Both of these calls originate from:

```
    public partial class DataOriginUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

and are not located inside of static methods.

E.G:

```
protected void btnCancelSyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblErrorMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    this.lblErrorMessage.Visible = false;

    int index = _syncOperation.Sequence - 1;
    Default.ForceLoadSyncOperation(index);
}
```

This all seems really quirky to me. Does this smell to anyone else? Not really sure how to untangle it, though, as I can't exactly create an instance of the Default page inside of a user control.

Thoughts? Thanks for reading.

```
protected void LoadSelectedSyncOperation(int? index)
{
    SyncOperationConfiguration[] syncOperations = CSServiceClient.GetInterfaceConfiguration().SyncOperationConfigurations.ToArray();

    PopulateSyncOperationsListView(syncOperations);
    SyncOperationConfiguration syncOperation = null;

    try
    {
        syncOperation = syncOperations[index.HasValue ? index.Value : 0];
    }
    catch
    {
        syncOperation = syncOperations[0];
    }

    ucDataOrigin.LoadSyncOperationData(syncOperation);
    Session["ConfigMenuActiveIndex"] = 1;
    menuConfiguration.Items[(int)Session["ConfigMenuActiveIndex"]].Selected = true;
    mvwConfiguration.ActiveViewIndex = (int)Session["ConfigMenuActiveIndex"];
}
```

Comment: Does the `Default.LoadSelectedSyncOperation` method depend on the ASP.NET page lifecycle somehow? Is there any reason that it couldn't be factored out into a separate 'helper' class?

Comment: `Default` instance is assigned to a static field on the `Default` class to be shared across instances of `Default`. I'm not sure what it is supposed to be doing but it is not thread-safe and will be assigning a new instance to the field on each page load. What do `LoadSelectedSyncOperation` and `ForceLoadSyncOperation` do?

Comment: @RoccoC5 It does not look like it. I think that whoever wrote this code before had the intention of using it like a 'helper method', but left it on the Default page -- and then ran into the snag and didn't think to extract the method out.

Comment: @RussCam I added the code for LoadSelectedSyncOperation, but it just keeps delving deeper. Agreed with it not being thread-safe!

Comment: Should this be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than stackoverflow?

Comment: @mydogisbox Yeah, probably. I had no idea that existed and saw that there was a refactoring tag for SO so I went for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the user control is contained within the `Default` page and the static member is being used as a shortcut to get the current instance of `Default`.  I would've done it this way:

```
Default defaultPage = this.Page as Default;
if (defaultPage != null)
{
    defaultPage.LoadSelectedSyncOperation(index);
}
```

Using a static member in this way is not safe.  It opens up the door for race conditions.  There is the potential risk that the user control is loaded in another page and calls `LoadSelectedSyncOperation()` on a separate request's instance of `Default`, thus wreaking all kinds of potential havoc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what LoadSelectedSyncOperation does but this code looks weird. Whenever you click btnCancelSyncOperation you end up calling this method on some page, but you never know on which of them. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: OK. Well, as long as it is not just me. Thank you everyone for the solid opinions. I will edit my initial post with the solution I come up with once I have refactored and ensured I did not break anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely say your concerns are valid. I can't think of any reason that this design would make sense, ever. This would throw a flag for me, too.

Based on your reply to my comment, if the `Default.LoadSelectedSyncOperation` is not dependent upon the Default page somehow, then I suggest it be refactored into a separate class (not an ASP.NET Page).

Whether it makes sense for the method or new class to be static or not is a separate concern and would be based on the logic contained within the method.